# How to build something & then include it in the classpath for the build of a subproject?

Tags: gradle

I have a situation where I have to compile something (drools) using an external compiler and include in the `classpath` something built by a subproject. I have all the dependencies and `classpath` items right but the only way I can think of to make this work is to build and install those 2 subproject items first so I can pull them from the local repo. Is there any way I can build and then add them to the `buildscript` `classpath` so that I don't have to install them?

So something like:

```
buildscript {

repositories {...}
dependencies {
...
   classpath group: 'this.group', name:'otherSubProject', version:'thisVersion'
...
}
```